# Is there any way to set "angular-bootstrap-colorpicker" color pointer to some color code value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, color-picker, two-way

I have used many mention angular colorpicker instances on a single page. I have encountered an issue when we have a color selected in one picker and have another picker where there is no color selected.

Below is the image of the picker with a value.

[image]

Below is the image of the picker on the same page but with empty value and it gets displayed like this.

[image]

I think that the picker should be initialised with empty value if the model value is empty and it should not use the values of the previously opened picker. What I'm looking for is a way to set pointer to top-left corner or restrict it to take previously selected value.

Setting default value here is very much possible but as my project is developed with two-way-binding fundamental; so if I will set some default value it will be bind to my DOM control as well which is not correct as per application structure.

Please share solution if somebody faced such issue and able to resolve it.

Comment: Default setting the `ng-model` of the colorpicker may be a solution.

Comment: No that won't work as we do no want to assign any default value permanently to control rather we want to assign it on temporary basis only when its gets opened.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use AngularJS `ng-init` directive ?

Comment: Thanks for answer but it will not work out in my case.